# Download and Concat PDF Documents into 1 PDF Document with PHP and JS

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

I am trying to combine several PDF pages into 1. The PDF documents are automatically downloaded upon accessing a link, it is dynamic based on the id_order passed.

```
echo "<script>";
  foreach ($ids as $updateids) {
     $url = '/webtools/index.php?controller=Adminxxx&type=label&id_order='.$updateids.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('Adminxxx');
  }
  echo "window.open('$url','_blank')";
echo "</script>";
```

The code above will not work when I click more than 1 checkbox. I would like to download the pages as one PDF for printing purpose.

I have read on FPDF and FPDI and its possibilities but I do have to download all the files beforehand, right? Currently, I am not able to download multiple document.

Else I am thinking of downloading all the PDF and use PDFTK to merge them before printing.

Any guide is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know still you have any query.

Answer (score -1):

**You have to download [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) library first.**

```
    <?php
    include('pdf/PDFMerger.php');
    $pdf = new PDFMerger;
    //$_POST['pdfFile'] = all the selected pdf files to merge
    if (!empty($_POST['pdfFile'])) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['pdfFile']); $i++) {
            //echo $_POST['pdfFile'][$i];
            $pdf->addPDF('Path of the pdf files/'.$_POST['pdfFile'][$i]);
        }
        $pdf->merge('file', 'path for saving/newfilename.pdf');
        echo 'success';
    } else {
        echo 'error';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: The issue also lies in the downloading as I can only download one. I have to download multiple before executing the codes you provided.

Comment: But this code merge all files in to one files then no need to download multiple files.

Comment: I do not understand your code as I need to retrieve the PDF first, correct? The dynamic link in my post automatically download PDF documents. May I know where do I set the dynamic links in your code then? I need to open the links to retrieve the files, right?

Comment: Do you have all the PDF url  or stored in you server or system ?

Comment: The PDF url is dynamic as I am using $updateids to generate dynamic links. Thus, I believe your solution works if I need to download the PDF first else I do not have any PDF to merge at all. That said, my checkbox is not working to download more than 1.

Comment: In for loop provide your dynamic generated url instead of $_POST['pdfFile'][$i].

// $pdf->addPDF('Path of the pdf files/'.$_POST['pdfFile'][$i]);
 $pdf->addPDF('Dynamic generated pdf url');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164522/discussion-between-priyank-and-enthu).

Comment: What's the PDFMerger class? You didn't provide any link or source of it. I hope it's not the one from the CodePlex Archive which uses an extremly outdated version of FPDI. A simple demo showing how to concatenate PDF files with FPDI can be found [here](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/concatenate-fake/).

Comment: @JanSlabon - Are you referring to https://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-merger/pricing/? Any open source or free PHP library to use?

Comment: I'm not refering to our merger component (would be a solution, too) but I blame this answer as it neither offers sources of the used class (PDFMerger) and I guess that this is a very outdated class which should not be suggested nowadays.

Comment: @JanSlabon - Noted. Thanks for pointing that out. I will check on a feasible solution.

Comment: @Priyank - I believe we have to download and store the PDF before-hand, even before we proceed with the PDF merge.

Comment: @Enthu yes you can do same way or you can give the url

Comment: @Priyank - Multiple download is not working at the moment.

Comment: give me 2 or 3 url of you pdf i will do it.

Comment: @Priyank - My URLs are dymanically created. I understand where you are coming from, if I do have the URLs before-hand, I can download it directly. I am creating the link on the fly.

Comment: @Enthu without url i m not able to help you.